# Return the text of a HREF from a list generated dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a table generated dynamically that may be represented as follows:

```
<a class="editlink" id="1" href="#">Entry_1</a>
<a class="editlink" id="2" href="#">Entry_2</a>
<a class="editlink" id="3" href="#">Entry_3</a>
<a class="editlink" id="4" href="#">Entry_4</a>
<a class="editlink" id="5" href="#">Entry_5</a>
```

I'm unable to get the text of the HREF anchor (i.e **'Entry_3'**). The following returns correctly the right index:

```
var index = $(".editlink").index(this);
```

but this one returns **always the last** element of the list:

```
var item_name = $(".editlink").eq(index).text();
```

**$(this).text() returns nothing**

**$(a#3).text() returns nothing** (remember also that the list is generated dinamically)

Thank you.

**I FOUND WHAT'S WRONG but don't know how to fix it:**

A LOOP generates the following table with a number of rows:

```
<tr>
    <td><a class="editlink" id="1" href="#">Item_1</a><td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><a class="delete_review" id="1" href="#"><img src="remove.png"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to delete the row (that part works) when the user clicks the image (.delete_review):

```
$(".delete_review").click(function() {
    var index = $(".editlink").index(this);
    var item_name = $(".editlink").eq(index).text();
    alert(item_name);
}
```

I noticed from the examples you provided that the script works if I call JQuery using the same class of the links (.editlink);

```
$(".editlink").click(function() {
```

but not if I use the class of the image:

```
$(".delete_review").click(function() {
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).text()`? It should work though, nevertheless. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: It's not clear... do you need the Text of the **clicked** link?

Comment: `$('a#3').text();` should return the value, as long as it's called after the link is created.

Comment: @davioooh, yes I need the text of the link. $(this) does not return anything

Comment: You'll have to provide more context, if `$(this).text()` isn't what you need. You've said `var index = $(".editlink").index(this);` returns the right index. What's `this` when you run that code, then?

Comment: Seems to me you want `$(this).closest('tr').find('.editlink').text()` then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the text of the anchor that was clicked, from within an event handler, it's:

```
var item_name = $(this).text();
```

---

Side note: Your `id` values are [valid for HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), but [not for HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and more significantly [not for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier); in CSS, an `id` value cannot *start* with a digit. This is significant because jQuery uses CSS-style selectors for querying DOM elements, so it's best to stick to valid CSS `id` values if you're going to use them in selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var item_name = '';
$(document).on("click", "a.editlink", function() {
    item_name = $(this).text();
});
```

Also, I'd recommend something like `href="#null"` as `href="#"` will jump the user to the top of the page.

Comment: What about if the first link is clicked? *edit:* Your `.on` call is not correct.

Comment: No-one mentioned clicking. I suspect you commented while I was adding the on statement, though. _edit_ Damnit, I *always* get them in the wrong order =]

Comment: Sorry, my comment reads really badly. Imagine me shrugging as I say "no-one mentioned clicking" rather than wagging my finger in your face, or something!

Comment: No worries :) You are right, and I didn't express myself very well either. I just did not think that a hardcoded solution is very helpful. Anyways, the second part is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of the third link (it has index `2`, since indices are 0-based):

```
var item_name = $(".editlink").eq(2).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with latest jQuery 1.7 and Chrome !

check jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GuhV/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#3').html();
```

I think that should do? :o this gets the html in the div id="3".
and why do you use a classname and an id name? you could make it so when you generate the urls they output like this:

```
<a class="editlink 1" href="#">Entry_1</a>

$('.editlink.1).html();
```